# Sample Count In Metal

Tags: ios, swift, textures, metal, metalkit

I am drawing texture in a quad with 4. then I am drawing a triangle with sample count 4. I feel there is no need to draw texture in a quad with 4 sample count. It affect performance. Is it possible use different sample count in a single program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use different MSAA sample counts with a single render pipeline state or within a single render pass (render command encoder), because each of these objects is immutably configured with the sample count. In order to achieve MSAA, the render pass has one or more attachments which must be *resolved* to produce a final image. If you need different sample counts for different draw calls (i.e., you want to draw some MSAA passes and some non-MSAA passes), you should first perform your multisample passes, then load the `resolveTexture`s of the final MSAA pass as the `texture`s of the corresponding attachments in subsequent passes, using a `loadAction` of `.load`, then perform your non-MSAA drawing.

Comment: In offscreen rendering I am processing the things with Sample count 4 and processing it to a texture. Is it possible to present that thing to screen with sample count 1